# Antd: How to override style of a single instance of a component

Tags: reactjs, antd

I'm using webpack to import the antd.less file in a global App.less file. Then I override some global styles and webpack bundles everthing:

```
// App.less
@import "~antd/dist/antd.less";
@import "./fonts.css";
@import "./reactSplitPane.css";      

@heading-color          : fade(#000, 100%);
@text-color             : fade(#000, 100%);
@text-color-secondary   : fade(#000, 100%);
@disabled-color         : fade(#000, 25%);
```

My webpack 2 config looks like that:

```
    {
        test: /\.less$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
            fallback: "style-loader",
            use: [
            { 
                loader: "css-loader", 
                options: { importLoaders: 1}
            },
            "less-loader"
            ]
        })
    },
    {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
            fallback: "style-loader",
            use: "css-loader"
        })
    }
```

Now, for example, I want to override the size of one instance of a Tabs component. What's the best way to do it?

Example for overriding the color of the bottom-line of the Tabs-Bar:

```
.ipf-appbar {
    font-size: 24px; // this applies to all text in the Tabs component
    border-bottom: 1px solid darkmagenta; // also applies to all border
}
.ant-tabs-bar {
    border-bottom: 1px solid darkmagenta; // this applies only to the desired div but is global
}
```

But this should be valid only for one component. The component looks like this (Typescript):

```
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import * as React from "react";
import { Tabs } from "antd";
import "./AppBar.less";

export class AppBar extends React.Component<undefined, undefined> {
    render() {
        return (
            // <Tabs className="ipf-appbar">
            <Tabs>
                <Tabs.TabPane tab="Start" key="1">Start</Tabs.TabPane>
                <Tabs.TabPane tab="Projekte" key="2">Projekte</Tabs.TabPane>
            </Tabs>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add your html code so I can make my example more specific

Comment: I'm using React with TS. See my updates.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should target `Tabs` component with css by adding a custom css class / id. Then you can customize that class/id in your css file. In your specific case where you add `.ipf-appbar` class you can style that specific component as follows:

```
.ipf-appbar .ant-tabs-bar {
    font-size: 24px; // this applies to all text in the Tabs component
    border-bottom: 1px solid darkmagenta; // also applies to all border
}
```

Comment: How would I override a given "nested" class for this component? E.g. `.ant-tabs-bar { border-bottom: 1px solid darkmagenta; }`. It should only apply to the one instance.

Comment: I needed to add a space ... `.ipf-appbar .ant-tabs-bar`. Works perfectly. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

This question is a bit old, but there's still an answer that is less static and offers more flexibility. Other answers have recommended adding custom classes to the intended component and then targeting specific parts of it through those custom classes from CSS or LESS.

But IMO it is not a perfect solution as it kind of *hides styles from JavaScript*, so later if you need to change them using JavaScript, you'll have to again look around for another solution for accessing those CSS (or LESS) rules to read or manipulate them using JavaScript.

Good news is though, **there's a better and more modern solution as well** that does not hide CSS from JavaScript and it is: ***CSS-in-JS***. Just use a library such as [Emotion](https://emotion.sh/docs/introduction) or [Styled-Components](https://styled-components.com/) and you're done.

- **Example:** This is for example how you can style a single instance of an [Ant's Search component](https://ant.design/components/input/#components-input-demo-search-input) using *Emotion*'s styled syntax:

```
const StyledSearch = styled(Search)`
  & .ant-input-group > .ant-input:first-child,
  .ant-input-group-addon:first-child {
    border-radius: var(--border-radius1);
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  }
  & .ant-input-search-button {
    background-color: var(--color-primary);
    border-radius: var(--border-radius1) !important;
    border-top-left-radius: 0 !important;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0 !important;
    & .anticon {
      color: var(--color-white);
    }
    &:hover {
      background-color: var(--color-primary);
    }
  }
`;
```

which turns this:

[image]

into this:

[image]

---

<sub>Note: Instead of using CSS variables as in the example above, you could (and it is recommended to) use Emotion's or Ant's theming features for more serious use cases.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution would be to create a `css` file for that component and override the style using the same class `antd` uses.

> antd default

```
.ant-menu-dark .ant-menu-item,
.ant-menu-dark .ant-menu-item-group-title,
.ant-menu-dark .ant-menu-item > a,
.ant-menu-dark .ant-menu-item > span > a {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.65);
}
```

> customized

```
.ant-menu-dark .ant-menu-item,
.ant-menu-dark .ant-menu-item-group-title,
.ant-menu-dark .ant-menu-item > a,
.ant-menu-dark .ant-menu-item > span > a {
  color: #e9631a !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import * as React from "react";
import { Tabs } from "antd";
import "./AppBar.less";

export class AppBar extends React.Component<undefined, undefined> {
    render() {
        return (
            <Tabs className="ipf-appbar">
                <Tabs.TabPane tab="Start" key="1">Start</Tabs.TabPane>
                <Tabs.TabPane tab="Projekte" key="2">Projekte</Tabs.TabPane>
            </Tabs>
        );
    }
}
```

AppBar.less:

```
.temp {
  @import '~antd/lib/tabs/style/index.less';

  @tabs-ink-bar-color: red;
}

.ipf-appbar {
  .temp();
}
```

The modified variable applys to the single instance. It's more clear and extendable.