# Restyle Ant-Design Tabs active tab bottom border

Tags: css, antd

I've been digging through the Ant-Design node_module trying to change the default color and default width of an active tab but have had no luck. Anyone know how to override it?

The problem is that I don't know which element has the border to begin with. Any help is very welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check https://pro.ant.design/docs/style#Override-the-component-style on how to override style .

**Refer dis answer too** [Antd: How to override style of a single instance of a component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42525035/antd-how-to-override-style-of-a-single-instance-of-a-component)

To figure out on what needs to be changed on your own, Inspect the element in browser.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 5):

you can go with:

```
.ant-tabs-tab.ant-tabs-tab-active {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #BF2D30 !important;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

**UPDATE**

This style will do as expected.

```
.ant-tabs-ink-bar {
  height: 5px;
  background: red !important;
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: yeah, why we put `border-bottom`? it will replace the original antd style and we should add `z-index: 2` to put our custom style in the front of original style

Answer (score 1):

You need use `tabBarStyle` props.
See docs: https://ant.design/components/tabs/

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem with this code:

```
  import './styles.less';

  const [tabIndex, setTabIndex] = useState('0');
  const borderClass = ['redBorder', 'greenBorder', 'blueGreyBorder'];

  <Tabs
      className={`tabs ${borderClass[tabIndex]}`}
      defaultActiveKey={tabIndex}
      onChange={onSetTabIndex}
    >
 // And in the styles.less:
` .tabs {
    margin-top: 17px;
    width: 100%;
 }
 .redBorder{
 .ant-tabs-ink-bar {
    background-color: #e94747;
   }
 }
.greenBorder{
  .ant-tabs-ink-bar {
    background-color: #24ad52;
   }
 }
.blueGreyBorder{
  .ant-tabs-ink-bar {
    background-color: #5b708b;
  }
}`
```

with the state we can change the class and use the cascade css to solve our problem