# How to update style element in Ant Design React component using Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, antd

I am quite new to React and I am trying to update the text color of the `Progress` React component from Ant Design - https://ant.design/components/progress/. I checked through the documentation of ant design but did not find any property or attribute for changing the text color. On doing inspect element, I found that it is using the css class `.ant-progress-circle .ant-progress-text`. Can anyone tell me how to change the color of component after using it? This is how I am using the component:

```
<Progress
          style={{
            position: 'absolute',
            top: 50,
            left: 750,
            color: '#C64242',
          }}
          width={155}
          percent={80}
          strokeColor={'#D64242'}
          strokeWidth={12}
          format={() => 'High'}
          type="circle"
        />
```

I am able to update positions (top, left) of the component, but somehow the color is not getting applied. I am not sure how to tackle this problem!

Comment: Try wrapping this in a div with style={{ color: '#C64242'}}

Comment: Can you please elaborate more? I tried like this and it did not work -
<div style={{ color: '#D64242'}}>
        <Progress
          style={{
            position: 'absolute',
            top: 50,
            left: 750,
            color: '#C64242',
          }}
          width={155}
          percent={80}
          strokeColor={'#D64242'}
          strokeWidth={12}
          format={() => 'High'}
          type="circle"
        />
      </div>

Comment: @AdityaBhattacharya can you tell what color is not getting applied? strokeColor or color you added via style?

Comment: The color added via style

Comment: @AdityaBhattacharya what version of antd are you using?

Comment: I am using this version - 4.19.5. I think this is the latest one available in unpkg

Comment: @AdityaBhattacharya Have you import this class 'antd/dist/antd.css' in this file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244128/discussion-between-devthiman-and-aditya-bhattacharya).

Comment: Yes I have imported the css. And sure we can continue the discussion in chat

Comment: @AdityaBhattacharya I uploaded a screen shot in the chat. Check that and then I think I found the reason for this and once you confirm I'll able to post the answer accurately. :)

Answer (score 2):

There are few style classes that applied to the text in Progress which you identified.

`.ant-progress-circle .ant-progress-text`.

And when Progress is 100% it applies `.ant-progress-status-success` style also to the text.

So to overcome this issue, need to override these styles Inside specific Progress element. That can be achieved by wrapping that `Progress` with a `div` and apply style changes to those `.ant-progress-circle .ant-progress-text` and `.ant-progress-status-success` classes which are inside this `div`.

**Progress Element**

```
{/* Here we wrap the Progress component with 'div' and override the style classes
 (.ant-progress-circle .ant-progress-text) styles provided by antd styles */}
  <div className="progress-div">
    <Progress
      style={{
        position: "absolute",
        top: 100,
        left: 250
      }}
      width={155}
      percent={percent}
      strokeColor={"#D64242"}
      strokeWidth={12}
      format={() => "High"}
      type="circle"
    />
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.progress-div .ant-progress-circle .ant-progress-text {
    color: #32a852;
 }
```

From this we can override the style of text which is inside that div.

If you want to change the text-color for different values of the progress, keep styles for each color and change those styles when each values.

for example -- CSS ---

```
.progress-low .ant-progress-circle .ant-progress-text {
    color: #32a852;
 }

.progress-mid .ant-progress-circle .ant-progress-text {
    color: #ffbf00;
 }

.progress-high .ant-progress-circle .ant-progress-text {
    color: #c64242;
 }
```

Now dynamically change the style class that need to apply.

```
<div className={style}> // dynamic style.
    <Progress
      // attributes
    />
  </div>
```

check this example [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-progress-bar-issue-71974731-bowuu6?file=/src/App.js) which have full demo of how to apply different text colors (style-classes) in different progress values.

Answer (score 2):

Simplest way to override antd components style is search class from developer tool(inspect element) and override the class.

for your example it will be

```
.ant-progress-text{
color:red !important
}
```

as a result it will override the style globally.
if you want to override the style for specific element only, just add wrapper to the component with css class and override the style
example

```
<div className="parent">
   <Progress
      style={{
        position: "absolute",
        top: 100,
        left: 250
      }}
      width={155}
      percent={percent}
      strokeColor={"#D64242"}
      strokeWidth={12}
      format={() => "High"}
      type="circle"
    />
</div>
```

and css will be

```
.parent .ant-progress-text{
    color:red !important
    }
```

and it will override style of that specific element only

Answer (score 1):

I think the only way to change the text color is to overwrite  `.ant-progress-text` class.
check this: [How to override style of a single instance of a component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42525035/antd-how-to-override-style-of-a-single-instance-of-a-component)

Comment: Unfortunately, overriding works at a global level, this way the color of all other components are getting changed. I want to only modify for a specific component, preferably using JavaScript so that I can control it dynamically through code and based on React userState hook .

Comment: @Hesam actually .`ant-progress-text` is a nested style class  that is wrapped by `.ant-progress-circle`. So we need to override both by wrapping with style class which have those override styles. I put an answer check that. :)